# Git: setting merge.ff breaks fast-forward merges forever

Tags: git, merge, fast-forward

I encounter a very weird problem in Git (version 2.10.1 (Apple Git-78)).

It seems that if I once set `merge.ff` to `false` in the local repo config, there is no way back for this repo. I just cannot unset it.

Here are the steps to reproduce:

```
git init

# Set merge.ff
git config --add merge.ff false

# Add some content and commit.
echo '.' >> file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -am "commit"

# Create a new branch.
git branch feature

git checkout feature
echo '.' >> file.txt
git commit -am "commit"
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

This merge creates a commit with message - as expected.

Now I unset the setting, and I expect that future fast-forward commits will create no extra commits. But surprisingly, that does not work.

```
git config --unset-all merge.ff

git checkout feature
echo '.' >> file.txt
git commit -am "commit"
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

I'd assume this merge should not create a commit, because there is no `merge.ff` setting, so the default should apply. But the commit gets created.

What I want: Having fast-forward commits working again in my repo. Is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 2):

> I'd assume this merge should not create a commit, because there is no merge.ff setting, so the default should apply. But the commit gets created.

The default is to fast-forward *if possible*, otherwise to make a merge commit.

A merge commit is necessary now, because the graph looks like this:

```
* 4667bf7 (feature) commit
| *   6663675 (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'feature'
| |\  
| |/  
|/|   
* | c12b7b3 commit
|/  
* 3c62604 commit
```

The merge base of `master` and `feature` is commit `c12b7b3...`:

```
$ git merge-base master feature
c12b7b3f68caf419c3088fae293c57cfed147f34
```

and the tip of `feature` is `4667bf7`, with the tip of `master` being `6663675`.  Neither of these two tips is equal to the merge base, so a merge is required.

Your configuration is OK:

```
$ git config --get merge.ff
$ cat .git/config
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[merge]
```

(It's rather obnoxious, but harmless, that `git config` leaves a bogus empty `[merge]` section in there; every additional `git config merge.<whatever>` adds another one when there's an empty one.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what I don't understand: If I leave out the `git config --add merge.ff false` and `--unset-all merge.ff`, then all of these merges *are* fast-forward. Why?

Comment: If the first op is a fast-forward, it does not create a merge commit. Look at the above graph: the commit that is on `master` that is ahead of the merge base `c12b7b3` is itself the merge commit that we made on `master`. If we *don't* make a merge commit on `master` (if we do a fast-forward non-merge instead), the name `master` would point to `c12b7b3`, and a subsequent `git merge feature` (fast-forward allowed instead of merge) would find that the current tip of `master` is the same as the merge base of `master` and `feature`, and hence also be able to fast-forward instead of merging.